# Landscape figures in Classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis, pdflscape

On Ubuntu 16.04, the `pdflscape` and `lscape` package no longer rotate a page correctly when using a vanilla [`classicthesis`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/?lang=en) package, but instead gives the error `Output loop---100 consecutive cycles` for each landscape page.

This can be recreated by simply adding the following code to any chapter:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{test.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Landscape figures in a plain `latex` document did seem to work. And replacing the figure by text while in the `classicthesis` environment does work, so the issue must be related to the combination of the figure environment and the `classicthesis` environment.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

**Mimimum working example**
A MWE can be found below, where the original `classicthesis` package has been stripped to the packages which could potentially influence the error

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
            ngerman,american,%
            ]{scrreprt}
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,pdfspacing,subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}                                        
\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
\usepackage{fontenc}     
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package          
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small} % format=hang,
\usepackage{subfig}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\listfiles
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\pagestyle{plain}
Testing
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{test.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
Testing
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I tried with your MWE and after removing `\selectlanguage{american}` (which gives an error about being an unknown option) your example compiles fine and I get a landscape page with an image rotated accordingly.

Comment: What are you using to compile your document? I tried with `pdflatex` from TeXLive 2016.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the check - I'm currently running with pdflatex from Texlive 2015, but will see if the error persists after upgrading to a later version. The error only appeared upon upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, so presumably a change occurred there.

Comment: For reference - upgrading to Texlive 2016 did not solve the problem.

Comment: You have to change the order of your packages: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the `float` package together with the float specifier `H` solves this problem.